# Copying lastRow on form submitted based to different sheet based on the answer provided in the form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to find a way of copying the last row of a form submission to another sheet within the spreadsheet I am working with. All of this would be based on the Value in column 2.

For my current spreadsheet, I have tried different ways but I have not been successful.

```
function copyLastRow(event) 
{  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ulIvWOQIH9MRg9RSW6Xg5iHRikOBFJ0L9XQ46Y_r_6I').getSheetByName('Sheet2');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // name of source sheet. 

var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1,1, 12).getValues();


 if(event.values[1]=='Yes')
 { 
  target.appendRow(event.values);
 }


// else if (event.values[1]=='Landlord')
  //   {
  //    var target2 = SpreadSheetApp.OpenById('1ulIvWOQIH9MRg9RSW6Xg5iHRikOBFJ0L9XQ46Y_r_6I').getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  // target2.appendRow(event.values);
// }
```

}

This code was modified by "Cooper"([copy last row onFormSubmit if the value on column 2 matches the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339989/copy-last-row-onformsubmit-if-the-value-on-column-2-matches-the-value/45340743#45340743)) and helped me get the last column of a form submission if the answer is Yes, but my Else if is not working to move the last row of the answer "No" into another sheet "Sheet4". Also, if you guys know a way to add more possible answers and each answer goes to its own sheet that would be great!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ulIvWOQIH9MRg9RSW6Xg5iHRikOBFJ0L9XQ46Y_r_6I/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's an installable form-submit trigger [for Sheets if the form submits to a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events). Since this trigger's `event.values` returns

> An array with values in the same order as they appear in the
>   spreadsheet :
>
> ['2015/05/04 15:00', 'amin@example.com', 'Bob', '27',
>   'Bill', '28', 'Susan', '25']

all you need to do is add this array as the last row of the sheet you want to copy to after checking the necessary conditions.